# nested for loop in windows batch file not executing properly

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below code and when it is run, the code in the REM 2 block does not work. If I change the order of REM 1 block and REM 2 block the first one works correctly.

Please advice if you faced a similar situation

Thanks,
Roshan

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A Count_tif=0
SET /A Count_lst=0
SET /A Count_cust_files = -1


FOR %%A IN (%Date%) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/-" %%B in ("%%~A") DO ( SET Today=%%D%%B%%C )
                       )

SET Today=%Today: =%


REM ********************** To generate .lst files for Customerx.txt ****************************
ECHO Generating .lst files

@FOR %%A IN (C:\Imaging\COMWC\SQR\Customer?.txt) DO SET /A Count_cust_files += 1


for /l %%x in (1, 1, %Count_cust_files%) do (


REM 1 block
FOR /f %%c IN (C:\Imaging\COMWC\SQR\Customer%%x.txt) DO (
FOR /f %%d IN ('dir /b /a-d \\albaix41\HPII_data\%Today%\WCBFMISWCIMGS%%x\%%c_*.tif') DO ECHO(%%d)>>\\albaix41\HPII_data\%Today%\WCBFMISWCIMGS%%x\%%c.lst
                                                         )                              

REM 2 block
FOR /f %%a IN (C:\Imaging\COMWC\SQR\Customer%%x.txt) DO (
FOR /f %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d \\albaix41\HPII_data\%Today%\WCBFMISWCIMGS%%x\%%a.tif') DO ECHO(%%b)>\\albaix41\HPII_data\%Today%\WCBFMISWCIMGS%%x\%%a.lst
                                                         )                                                       


                                              )
```

Comment: Do your tif filenames have spaces or & or % or ! characters?  One set of tif files doesn't have the `_*` in them, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, since you haven't said what you mean by 'doesn't "work"' that there may be two problems.

First one is that you have <kbd>></kbd> in the #2 block, but <kbd>>></kbd> in the #1 block. <kbd>></kbd> will create the file anew on each iteration (you you'll get only the last iteration.) <kbd>>></kbd> appends to any existing file or creates a new file if the file doesn't already exist, hence it will accumulate data.

The second problem is `echo(whatever)`.

`echo(` will produce a new line if it is provided with no data to `echo`. `echo` on its own will generate an `echo status report`, that is, `echo is ON` (or OFF)

Hence, `echo(%%b)` does not do as you appear to expect. `echo(%%b` will display `%%b` -or a blank line if `%%b` is undefined. **Here's the critical point** - the following <kbd>)</kbd> then does **not** match the <kbd>(</kbd> in the echo, but matches the <kbd>(</kbd> in a `FOR`.

Solution: replace `echo(%%b)` with `echo(%%b` . If you really want the contents of `%%b` shown within round brackets, then use `echo((%%b)`

Answer (score 0):

A problem is this line includes a trailing space and you are not using double quotes to handle spaces.  I do see the following set statement, but it's better to realise the issue with this particular space.

```
DO ( SET Today=%%D%%B%%C )
:: use this instead:
DO (SET Today=%%D%%B%%C)
```

While this works with the set /a command it's better to use the following syntax - whitespace matters in some places in batch files and if you get used to putting spaces within variable names then it will bite you one day:

```
DO SET /A Count_cust_files += 1
:: use this instead:
DO SET /A Count_cust_files+=1
```

This is a better way to generate a timestamp for a file:

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Comment: Um - nope. the `SET Today=%Today: =%` line following strips out that space (but agreed, it's a complicated way to do it.) The real problem is just a leetle more subtle... :)

Comment: @Magoo  I did comment on that following set statement.